# WCF SSL Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get asp.net client application to make a secure call to a wcf service. it fails with the message above.

Client is ASP.net 3.5 hosted locally (localhost) on windows 10 pro laptop in IIS and Server is asp.net 3.5 also hosted locally on the same windows 10 pro laptop in IIS, as a separate website. Ultimately I am trying to setup client certificate authentication, but, I'm not even doing that part yet. I'm just trying to get ssl working between client and server. server is WCF service. I have self signed root cert, ssl cert, and client cert all in the correct stores.  I setup client to use client cert via behaviors.

I built a test windows application as a wcf client. set it up with the same endpoint configuration and it works. I tried making the call from a different machine with the asp.net app and it failed, same error.

I traced with message analyzer and it appears to work from TLS perspective.

I just want to be able to do development on the client and server on my laptop. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my setup or is this not something I can do?

BTW with no SSL it does seem to work fine. I can make the call no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple. IIS_IUSRS needs to be granted access to the private key because I am using AppPoolIdentity.